# Android - OnScreen Keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I know, it's asked many times, but for old Android versions and not all solutions working.

I need to programmatically control onscreen keyboard on Android 10 system:

- Show onscreen keyboard when I want, not when want Android system (!).
- Hide onscreen keyboard when I want, not when want Android system (!).
- Check whether onscreen keyboard is showed.
- Prevent system from showing/hidding onscreen keyboard - only I will manipulate with it (!).

Code can be in kotlin/java.

Answer (score 1):

Add these two properties to your parent layout (ex: Linear Layout, Relative Layout)

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

in your activity :

```
this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Alternatively,

1. you could also declare in your manifest file's activity

   ```
   <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
   <activity android:name=".Main"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
     >
   ```
2. If you have already been using android:windowSoftInputMode for a value like adjustResize or adjustPan, you can combine two values:

   ```
    <activity
     ...
     android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"
     ...
     >
   ```

show keyboard programmatically:

```
    public static boolean showKeyboard(View view) {
    if (view == null) {
        return false;
    }
    try {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        view.requestFocus();
        return inputManager.showSoftInput(view, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
    return false;
}
```

hide keyboard :

```
public static void hideKeyboard(View view) {
    if (view == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (!imm.isActive()) {
            return;
        }
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        view.clearFocus();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

on keyboard show listener :

```
public static void OnkeyBoardShowListener(final Activity activity) {
final View activityRootView = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
 @Override
  public void onGlobalLayout() {
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
    int heightRoot = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight();
    int heightDiff = heightRoot - rect.bottom;
    if (heightDiff > dpToPx(activity, 200)) {
          //Keyboard is open
    }else if (heightDiff < dpToPx(activity, 200)) {
         //Keyboard is close
    }
   }
 });
}
```

convert Dp to Px :

```
private static float dpToPx(Context context, int dp) {
 DisplayMetrics metrics =  context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
 return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,dp, metrics);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Behnam Nasehi, I will try it on Monday when I will be in the work.

Comment: Your code looks good, very good and promising! BUT for me NOT working and I don't know why. And this is the reason why I don't like Android. Especially keyboard handling is horrible.

Comment: At least, I found, in system settings is "Input methods and Languages -> Physical keyboard -> Show OnScreen Keyboard -> On/Off" - this settings "interfere" all programming solutions which I found on internet. I had to disable/enable this settings too for complete hide/show onscreen keyboard. Because I am developing for device MC2200 I did it with "EMDK Profile manage -> Ui manager -> Virtual Keyboard state -> Show/Hide". I can accept your answer, but without it I can't.